# Can JavaScript run C without any configurations?

Tags: javascript, node-postgres

In the description of the [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) package, there is a sentence: "Pure JavaScript and optional native libpq bindings."

Does that mean that I can run C code from JavaScript? Or "bindings" here means something else?

Comment: You cannot run C code unaltered in JavaScript.

Comment: Its means you can call C code via JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sentence means there are native libpq <-> Node.js bindings available.

You can run C (or other compiled) code in Node.js (and Deno probably too), but not in browsers etc. without compiling that code to e.g. WebAssembly.

Comment: Thanks! What is this "bindings" technology, you are talking about? Can you give me some wiki page, please, so that I will know where to start learning about it?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/n-api.html is a good starting point.